# Suppress scientific notation in sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I was trying to plot a confusion matrix nicely, so I followed [scikit-learn's newer version 0.22's in built plot confusion matrix function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix). However, one value of my confusion matrix value is 153, but it appears as 1.5e+02 in the confusion matrix plot: 
[image]

Following the [scikit-learn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix), I spotted this parameter called `values_format`, but I do not know how to manipulate this parameter so that it can suppress the scientific notation. My code is as follows.

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

# import some data to play with

X = pd.read_csv("datasets/X.csv")
y = pd.read_csv("datasets/y.csv")

class_names = ['Not Fraud (positive)', 'Fraud (negative)']

# Split the data into a training set and a test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Run classifier, using a model that is too regularized (C too low) to see
# the impact on the results
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)


np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
titles_options = [("Confusion matrix, without normalization", None),
                  ("Normalized confusion matrix", 'true')]
for title, normalize in titles_options:
    disp = plot_confusion_matrix(logreg, X_test, y_test,
                                 display_labels=class_names,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Greens,
                                 normalize=normalize, values_format = '{:.5f}'.format)
    disp.ax_.set_title(title)

    print(title)
    print(disp.confusion_matrix)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Use `plt.grid(False)` to turn off the gridlines.

Comment: Try something like `values_format='d'` and see if that suits your purpose.

Comment: `values_format=''` just leaves a standard way to display the numbers. `'.2g'` is the default for this plot function, which displays `153` as `1.5e+02` and is quite weird as default.  More info about the formats the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just remove ".format" and the {} brackets from your call parameter declaration:

```
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(logreg, X_test, y_test,
                                 display_labels=class_names,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Greens,
                                 normalize=normalize, values_format = '.5f')
```

In addition, you can use `'.5g'` to avoid decimal 0's

Taken [from source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py#L91)

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone using `seaborn`´s `heatmap` to plot the confusion matrix, and none of the answers above worked. You should turn off scientific notation in confusion matrix `seaborn` with `fmt='g'`, like so:

```
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix,annot=True, fmt='g')
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be the latest correct answer!

Answer (score 6):

Simply pass values_format=''
Example:

```
plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, Y_test, values_format = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer `scikit-learn` versions (`version >= 1.0`) use parameter `values_format` for `sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.plot` method.

[scikit-learn ConfusionMatrixDisplay Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.plot)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    random_state=0)
clf = SVC(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions, labels=clf.classes_)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,
                              display_labels=clf.classes_)

# # #
# added `values_format` in contrast to original sklearn docs
# # #
disp.plot(values_format="d")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the only answer considering the new `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` class